# Single use/visit presigned url to view S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I am attempting to generate a presigned url that only allows one visit/use of the url.

I have been trying just using an expire time but from what I have tested anything under 70 seconds always gives an expired url error.

```
aws s3 presign s3://bucket/object --expires-in 70
```

The other alternative would be a short url expire time (e.g. 5 seconds) but I cannot get anything under 70 seconds to work without an expired url error.

Answer (score 0):

If anything under 70 seconds gives you an error, your clock is almost certainly wrong on the machine where you are generating the signed URL.

Expiration is calculated as `--expires-in` seconds in the future relative to the clock on the machine where you are running aws-cli.  There's an assumption that this is a trusted environment (your credentials are there) and the clock is also trusted to have been set accurately.

(The clock on the machine where the browser is being used to access the URL doesn't matter.)

Note that the fixed expiration time associated with a given URL is shown in the error message.